# Mutating elements in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, methods, iterator

Ok so I want to subtract 9 to numbers(elements in an array) over 9:

```
finalCredDigits = [10, 8, 18, 9, 16, 6, 16, 5, 14, 3, 14, 6, 10, 5, 8]
```

Thats what I tried

```
finalCredDigits.forEach(arr =>{
  if(arr > 9){
    finalCredDigits.push(arr - 9);
  } 
});
```

```
Output = [10, 8, 18, 9, 16, 6, 16, 5, 14, 3, 14, 6, 10, 5, 8, 1, 9, 7, 7, 5, 5, 1]
```

I know its cuz the result is being pushed in the array but i want to mutate it and replace the answer with numbers over 9

Comment: something like `finalCredDigits.forEach((item, index) =>{ if (item > 9) finalCredDigits[index] -=9; })`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
let finalCredDigits = [10, 8, 18, 9, 16, 6, 16, 5, 14, 3, 14, 6, 10, 5, 8]

finalCredDigits = finalCredDigits.map(number => {
 if (number > 9) {
   return number - 9
 }

  return number
})

console.log(finalCredDigits)
```

Comment: You are not mutating the array

Comment: Specifically the `map()` method creates a ***new*** array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a *similar but new* array, you should use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const finalCredDigits = [10, 8, 18, 9, 16, 6, 16, 5, 14, 3, 14, 6, 10, 5, 8];
const newFinalCredDigits = finalCredDigits.map(v => {
  if (v > 9) {
    return v - 9;
  } else {
    return v;
  }
});

console.log(newFinalCredDigits.join());
console.log("Is new array?", newFinalCredDigits !== finalCredDigits);
```

If you want to **mutate the array itself** with [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), you should use the callback's additional parameters:

```js
const finalCredDigits = [10, 8, 18, 9, 16, 6, 16, 5, 14, 3, 14, 6, 10, 5, 8];
finalCredDigits.forEach((v, i, array) => {
  if (v > 9) {
    array[i] = v - 9;
  }
});

console.log(finalCredDigits.join());
```

But functional programming usually implies preferring *immutable over mutable states,* so if your array is shared and we'd mutate it with `Array.forEach()`, it would be considered a code smell. Therefore I'd use a [regular for-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) instead:

```js
const finalCredDigits = [10, 8, 18, 9, 16, 6, 16, 5, 14, 3, 14, 6, 10, 5, 8];
{
  const l = finalCredDigits.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    if (finalCredDigits[i] > 9) finalCredDigits[i] -= 9;
  }
}

console.log(finalCredDigits.join());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign to the array index to replace the element, not push a new element.

`forEach()` passes a second argument to the callback function, containing the current index. You can use this for the assignment.

```js
const finalCredDigits = [10, 8, 18, 9, 16, 6, 16, 5, 14, 3, 14, 6, 10, 5, 8];

finalCredDigits.forEach((el, i) =>{
  if(el > 9){
    finalCredDigits[i] = el - 9;
  } 
});

console.log(finalCredDigits);
```

Comment: I would also use the third argument (the array itself) to not create closure.